# Pandas .dropna() on specify attribute

Tags: python, pandas

I have this code to drop null values from column Type, specifically looking at Dog.

```
cd.loc[cd['Type'] == 'Dog'].dropna(subset = ['Killed'], inplace = True)
```

I would like to dropna when the ['Killed'] column associating with Type = Dog has NaN value.

The code above generate this pandas error:

```
 A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame
```

Is there another way where can I dropna on ['Killed'] when ['Type'] == 'Dog'?

(This is my first post), sorry if I can't explain properly
Cheers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Very similar to @BrenBarn's answer but using `drop` and `inplace`

```
cd.drop(cd[(cd.Type == 'Dog') & (cd.Killed.isnull())].index, inplace=True)
```

#### Setup

```
cd = pd.DataFrame([
        ['Dog', 'Yorkie'],
        ['Cat', 'Rag Doll'],
        ['Cat', None],
        ['Bird', 'Caique'],
        ['Dog', None],
    ], columns=['Type', 'Killed'])
```

#### Solution

```
cd.drop(cd[(cd.Type == 'Dog') & (cd.Killed.isnull())].index, inplace=True)

cd
```

[image]

---

Equivalently with DeMorgan's law

```
cond1 = cd.Type == 'Dog'
cond2 = cd.Killed.isnull()
cd[~cond1 | ~cond2]
```

---

A silly one, because I felt like it!

```
cd.groupby('Type', group_keys=False) \
    .apply(lambda df: df.dropna(subset=['Killed']) if df.name == 'Dog' else df)
```

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like what you are saying is you want to remove rows where Type is "Dog" and Killed is `NaN`.  So just select the negation of that condition:

```
cd = cd.loc[~((cd.Type=="Dog") & cd.Killed.isnull())]
```

Comment: Why not `cd[(cd.Type=="Dog") & pd.notnull(cd.Killed)]` or `cd[(cd.Type=="Dog") & np.isfinite(cd.Killed)]`

Comment: @NehalJWani: Those would *retain* rows where Type is Dog *and* Killed is non-null.  But the question (as I understand it) asks to retain rows where Type is not dog *or* Killed is non-null.

Comment: Oh. I see. My bad.

Comment: Thanks for helping :D