# Drop NaN rows except one column is not duplicated in Pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Given a dataframe as follows:

```
   city district
0    bj       dc
1    bj       xc
2    bj       hd
3    bj       cy
4    bj      NaN
5    sh       pd
6    sh       hp
7    sh       xh
8    sh      NaN
9    gz      NaN
10   sz      NaN
```

How could I remove rows whose `district` is `NaN`, but except for the city which has `district`? For example, `gz` and `sz` won't be removed since it only has `NaN` district, row `4` and `8` will be removed since they have `district` values which are not `NaN`s.

The expected result:

```
  city district
0   bj       dc
1   bj       xc
2   bj       hd
3   bj       cy
4   sh       pd
5   sh       hp
6   sh       xh
7   gz      NaN
8   sz      NaN
```

Many thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pandas .dropna() on specify attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39241346/pandas-dropna-on-specify-attribute)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Groupby city and drop NaN only if group has more than one row.

```
df = df.groupby('city',as_index=False).apply(
    lambda x: x.dropna() if len(x)>1 else x)
```

This will give you an additional index level. To drop it:

```
df.index = df.index.droplevel(0)
```

Answer (score 2):

Code works:

```
m1 = df['district'].isna()
m2 = df[['city']].duplicated(keep=False)
df[~(m1 & m2)]
```

Out:

```
   city district
0    bj       dc
1    bj       xc
2    bj       hd
3    bj       cy
5    sh       pd
6    sh       hp
7    sh       xh
9    gz      NaN
10   sz      NaN
```

Comment: I think there is a problem. If `sz` has two `np.nan`, then are you expecting `sz` to be shown or removed?

Comment: Keep only one if `sz` has two `np.nan`.